# Hover effects remain after clicking external link

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

When I hover over a clickable link on my homepage, the styling changes as expected (i.e. the border becomes blue or the link has text-decoration). However, when I click the link to open in a new window (either it has `target=_blank` set or if I *command + click* the link), that link's styling persists until I click elsewhere on the page.

Why does the styling not revert back immediately?

Here are a few things I've tried:

- `a, a:link, a:active` is set to `text-deocration: none;`. On hover, I've put a bottom border instead of changing text-deocration to underline.

`a:hover, a:focus {
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
 }`

- I've tried playing around with `a, a:visited`, but as I read, I cannot change `text-decoration`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector
- I've ensured that Google Analytics tracking returns true and that it's not stopping event propagation.

To note, I'm using **Bootstrap**.

Would appreciate some other idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the link it becomes focused. Change your second CSS rule to remove the `a:focus`.

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean....

```a:hover, a:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}```

I even tried adding `outline: none;` to it form other posts that I read, but it did not work.

Comment: just remove the `a:focus`. When you click on an element that supports focus it becomes focused. So hovering or focusing on the link will cause it to be styled like a hover.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed `a:focus` for one link, and it worked, but the header links and footer links don't have an `a:focus`. I even searched the entire codebase for `:focus`, and there's nothing those sections are inheriting form. I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks again.